# Why do I get different times when using analogRead() inside while loop?

Tags: arduino-uno, timers, analogread

I have the following code which checks the latency of another board.

```cpp
    int triggerPin = 13;
    int dataPin = 9;
    int ejectorPin = A0;
    unsigned long t_start = 0;
    unsigned long t_end = 0;
    unsigned long t_total = 0;
    int value = 0;
    
    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      pinMode(triggerPin, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(ejectorPin, INPUT);
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }
    
    void loop() {
      t_start = micros();
      while (value < 10 ) {
        digitalWrite(triggerPin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(dataPin, HIGH);
        delay(5.0);
        digitalWrite(dataPin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW);
        delay(1.0);
        value = analogRead(ejectorPin);
      }
      t_end = micros();
    
      t_total = (t_end - t_start);
      Serial.println(double(t_total) / 1000);
```

Note that I'm using `analogRead()` inside the while loop. With this method I get **18.3 msec**. However, if I use the `analogRead()` in the while condition:

```cpp
    void loop() {
      t_start = micros();
      while (analogRead() < 10 ) {
        .
        .
        .
```

then I get **30.2 msec**. I thought assigning value of `analogRead()` to a variable would take longer but here it's the opposite.

**Can someone please explain the reason behind this behaviour?**

Comment: What voltage are you supplying to A0? Is it consistent between runs of the program? How consistent are the printed values across loop iterations?

Comment: Your delays will be completely hiding any variance in the analog read timing. Your supposed results are meaningless to us.

Comment: @EdgarBonet As far I can tell the both the input voltage and the printed values are pretty consistent.

Comment: @Majenko I just had an experience colleague tell me the same thing. We're now using a two channel oscilloscope to visually check the time difference.

Comment: @Majenko But nonetheless, just moving `analogRead()` shouldn't introduce 12 msec difference.

Comment: @Farahi It won't be the analogRead. It'll be whatever is "triggering" the analogRead. The analogRead is insignificant in the scale of things.

Comment: @Majenko But the same thing which is triggering the analogRead inside the loop is also triggering the analogRead when its in the while condition.

Comment: And is the timing of that "same thing" absolutely precisely the same, or could your delays be affecting how your sampling happens? Remember: you will only ever be taking a single sample every 6 milliseconds or so whichever method you're using. Does that slow sample frequency even make sense for what you're sampling?

Comment: @Majenko I let both methods run for over 40 mins. The results were pretty much as I mentioned in the post.

Comment: @Farahi So? With a 6ms granularity of sampling you have an accuracy of ±6ms, or "within 12 ms of reality". Oh look...  30-18 is 12...  What a surprise...

Comment: @Majenko There's no need for passive aggressiveness. I'm new to all this so my questions may come across as dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your examples use a while loop, so the while loop is not the issue.

An analogue read, with the prescalers unchanged, takes 104 µs. So, what you are really measuring is your 6 ms delays, plus a slight amount extra for the other code.

Since your first while loop necessarily takes 6+ ms, then you will naturally get a result which is a multiple of 6 ms. This appears to be happening, so you are getting two loops (18 ms). This doesn't prove a huge amount.

---

You need to read up on the [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency)

To get accurate sampling results you need to sample at twice the rate at which things change. Your first results may merely be the results of aliasing. Your 6 ms delays may cause you to take one sample on one transition, and another sample (maybe) a couple of transitions later. Thus your results are meaningless.